# Java files with cyclic imports

Tags: java, import, javac

I am trying to understand how `javac` deals with cyclic imports. After few attempts, I got the below code to be compiled:

```
package com.test.p1;    
import com.test.p2.ClassP2;    
public class ClassP1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ClassP1 loaded");           
        ClassP2.testP2();       
    }
}
```

And

```
package com.test.p2;    
import com.test.p1.ClassP1;    
public class ClassP2 {

    public static void testP2() {
        System.out.println("ClassP2 loaded");
    }
}
```

When I compiled `ClassP2.java` first, I was expecting it to fail as `ClassP1.java` was not yet compiled and no `class` file was generated. Yet, it compiled ok, and generated `ClassP2.class` and `ClassP1.class`. Running ClassP1 worked fine as well.

Now my question is how did `javac` generate class file for ClassP1 when I only compiled ClassP2. And why does this not happen when cyclic reference is not there - i.e. when ClassP2 imports ClassP1, but ClassP1 does not import ClassP2 ?

I am still new to Java and trying to understand how compilation works.

Comment: Show us your `javac` compile commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing cyclic going on here.  It sounds like you, along with a lot of other people, confuse import with class loading.

All the import statement does is allow you to use the short name to refer to a Java class in your code:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public V find() {
    ResultSet rs = null;  // You can type ResultSet instead of java.sql.ResultSet
}
```

The import statement won't help you if the short name is ambiguous (e.g. `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` in the same class).

The byte code for `java.sql.ResultSet` is not loaded into the JVM until your code needs it at runtime.

Comment: If you use any of the type's members, the class needs to be on the classpath at compile time though.

Comment: Of course, but that does not imply a problem with cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a result of cyclic imports,  it is a result of importing ClassP1 in ClassP2.java and `javac` being able to find the source for ClassP1 based on the arguments you passed to `javac` and the location from which you executed the command.

See the -sourcepath option in the docs for [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> -sourcepath sourcepath
>   Specify the source code path to search for class or interface definitions. As with the user class path, source path entries are separated by semicolons (;) and can be directories, JAR archives, or ZIP archives. If packages are used, the local path name within the directory or archive must reflect the package name.
>   Note: Classes found through the class path may be subject to automatic recompilation if their sources are also found. See Searching For Types.